# passing in cookie python requests

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm using two different modules for the code I'm writing.
I'm using dryscrape to log into netflix, and than using requests to do the other stuff. However, using dryscrape I was able to get bunch of cookies using session.cookies(), which returned me an array of cookies. So I am trying to pass these cookies to a requests using requests library.

However, I'm currently having an issue doing that. Requests takes in a dictionary of cookie, which I did.

Less talking, here's the code to simplify this situation..

This is the cookie format I got using dryscrape Session.cookies()

```
["NetflixCookies=true; domain=.netflix.com; path=/", "hcVisitorId=b0ada616-e472-4a89-9bd6-35c6adbdf48a; expires=Sat, 26-Nov-2016 07:30:55 GMT; domain=.help.netflix.com; path=/", "cL=1448609468009%7C144860945956982159%7C144860945964708782%7C%7C5%7C; domain=.www.netflix.com; path=/", "netflixHelpCenterLocale=en-US; domain=.help.netflix.com; path=/", "JSESSIONID=8641E508022EEE2E146073D62A320319; HttpOnly; domain=help.netflix.com; path=/", "memclid=b0ada616-e472-4a89-9bd6-35c6adbdf48a; expires=Sat, 26-Nov-2016 07:31:03 GMT; domain=.netflix.com; path=/"]
```

However requests only takes in a dictionary, so therefore I did

```
cookies_info = dict(cookies_are= ''.join(cookies))
print cookies_info
search_query = 'Sons of Anarchy'
second_requests =  requests.get('http://www.netflix.com/search/'+search_query,cookies=cookies_info).text
```

It does not work for me at all, it does not log into netflix, and asks for me to login doing such. I'm assuming it has to do with me passing in the cookies properly with proper format!

Comment: How did you get those cookies, exactly? You have a series of `Set-Cookie` headers, not the key-value pairs they represent. You'd want to send a dictionary with `{'NetflixCookies': 'true', 'hcVisitorId': 'b0ada616-e472-4a89-9bd6-35c6adbdf48a', ... etc ...}` instead.

Comment: Also, if you already *have* a session object with cookies, you don't need to re-set those cookies. The same session object will take care of sending the right `Cookie` header back to the same server.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hey! I'm using session.cookies() function which returns me an array of cookies. Also, the reason why I am passing in cookies is because the session that I'm using expires as I start making a fresh get requests instead of dryscrape session. Therefore I'd need to pass in cookies.

Comment: According to requests documentation, they only tend to accept cookie in a dictionary format, but the way dryscrape returned me cookies was in a fat list of an array, therefore I had to use .join and set it to a dictionary before I pass it into my get requests!

Comment: You gave your dictionary an arbitrary key, that's not how it works. Instead, use key-value pairs *per cookie*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, gotcha I'll give it a stab and keep you on loop!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Something like this? {'cookies_are': u'NetflixCookies:true; domain:.netflix.com; path:/hcVisitorId:b0ada616-e472-4a89-9bd6-35c6adbdf48a; expires:Sat, 26-Nov-2016 07:30:55 GMT; domain:.help.netflix.com; path:/cL:1448609468009%7C144860945956982159%7C144860945964708782%7C%7C5%7C; domain:.www.netflix.com; path:/netflixHelpCenterLocale:en-US; domain:.help.netflix.com; path:/JSESSIONID:8641E508022EEE2E146073D62A320319; HttpOnly; domain:help.netflix.com; path:/memclid:b0ada616-e472-4a89-9bd6-35c6adbdf48a; expires:Sat, 26-Nov-2016 07:31:03 GMT; domain:.netflix.com; path:/'}

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not entirely sure what you meant, and not sure how to do it with python syntax, you mind showing it to me on python on how it's done? Using the array I provided up in the post to make it compatible with my requests!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list with `Set-Cookie` header results. These contain a *key-value pair* plus some metadata.

For example, your first cookie header is this:

```
NetflixCookies=true; domain=.netflix.com; path=/
```

It tells the browser your cookie name is `NetflixCookies`, it's value is `true` and the cookie should only be used when contacting a server in the `netflix.com` domain, with paths starting with `/` (the whole server).

However, when you *send* cookies back to the server, all that metadata is not needed. You only send the key-value pairs. As such, the `cookies` argument to `requests` methods takes a dictionary of those key-value pairs, not the metadata. So for the above cookie, you'd use this:

```
cookies = {'NetflixCookies': 'true'}
```

For the other cookies you'll have to extract their cookie name and value, and use the names as keys in the dictionary.

To parse your headers, you could just use the `cookilib.parse_ns_headers()` function; it returns a list with tuple pairs *per header*; the first tuple is your key-value pair:

```
>>> from http.cookiejar import parse_ns_headers                                                                                                                                                            
>>> cookies = ["NetflixCookies=true; domain=.netflix.com; path=/", "hcVisitorId=b0ada616-e472-4a89-9bd6-35c6adbdf48a; expires=Sat, 26-Nov-2016 07:30:55 GMT; domain=.help.netflix.com; path=/", "cL=1448609468009%7C144860945956982159%7C144860945964708782%7C%7C5%7C; domain=.www.netflix.com; path=/", "netflixHelpCenterLocale=en-US; domain=.help.netflix.com; path=/", "JSESSIONID=8641E508022EEE2E146073D62A320319; HttpOnly; domain=help.netflix.com; path=/", "memclid=b0ada616-e472-4a89-9bd6-35c6adbdf48a; expires=Sat, 26-Nov-2016 07:31:03 GMT; domain=.netflix.com; path=/"]
>>> for result in parse_ns_headers(cookies):
...     print(result[0])
...
('NetflixCookies', 'true')
('hcVisitorId', 'b0ada616-e472-4a89-9bd6-35c6adbdf48a')
('cL', '1448609468009%7C144860945956982159%7C144860945964708782%7C%7C5%7C')
('netflixHelpCenterLocale', 'en-US')
('JSESSIONID', '8641E508022EEE2E146073D62A320319')
('memclid', 'b0ada616-e472-4a89-9bd6-35c6adbdf48a')
```

You can put that result straight into a dictionary:

```
cookie_dictionary = dict(res[0] for res in parse_ns_headers(session_cookies))
```

For your specific example, this produces:

```
>>> dict(res[0] for res in parse_ns_headers(cookies))
{'NetflixCookies': 'true', 'hcVisitorId': 'b0ada616-e472-4a89-9bd6-35c6adbdf48a', 'cL': '1448609468009%7C144860945956982159%7C144860945964708782%7C%7C5%7C', 'netflixHelpCenterLocale': 'en-US', 'JSESSIONID': '8641E508022EEE2E146073D62A320319', 'memclid': 'b0ada616-e472-4a89-9bd6-35c6adbdf48a'}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
{'JSESSIONID': '8641E508022EEE2E146073D62A320319',
 'NetflixCookies': 'true',
 'cL': '1448609468009%7C144860945956982159%7C144860945964708782%7C%7C5%7C',
 'hcVisitorId': 'b0ada616-e472-4a89-9bd6-35c6adbdf48a',
 'memclid': 'b0ada616-e472-4a89-9bd6-35c6adbdf48a',
 'netflixHelpCenterLocale': 'en-US'}
```